# Unpivot con nombre de columnas booleanas en AWS Redshift

Tags: redshift

Tengo un problema que aún no logro resolver utilizando Queries en AWS Redshift.

Tengo la siguiente tabla, llamemosla tabla_bienes

```
nombre      autos       casas       animales
jorge       true                    true
patricia               true         false
matias      false      true     
ines        true       true         true
cristina               true         true
```

Pero me gustaria por medio de una consulta en AWS Redshift formatearla de esta manera

```
nombre      bien
jorge       autos
jorge       animales
patricia    casas
matias      casas
ines        autos
ines        casas
ines        animales
cristina    autos
cristitna   casas
```

Cualquier comentarios seria de gran ayuda!